# Qt and coroutines

Tags: c++, qt, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have this class:

my_class.hpp

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYCLASS_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    MyClass(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    void doWork() { QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, [this](){ emit workFinished("TEST"); }); }

  signals:
    void workFinished();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_HPP
```

And I need to achieve something like that:

```
void function()
{
  MyClass myClass;

  qDebug() << "Doing the work...";
  myClass.doWork();
  // waiting until the workFinished() signal is emitted
  doSomethig();
  qDebug() << "Work done";
}
```

Can I do that with coroutines? I don't want to fill the code with lambdas inside other lambdas.
Thank you

******* EDIT *******
For anyone wondering if that's possible, here is the code to do something like that.

// signal_waiter.hpp

```
#ifndef SIGNALWAITER_HPP
#define SIGNALWAITER_HPP

#include <QObject>
#if __has_include(<coroutine>)
#include <coroutine>
#else
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#endif
#include <QDebug>

// apply a function to a variadic argument, to be placed in an utility file
template <class F, class... Args>
void for_each_argument(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{((void)std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
}

class SignalWaiter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
#if __has_include(<coroutine>)
    using coroutine_handle = std::coroutine_handle<>;
#else
    using coroutine_handle = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<>;
#endif

    struct Result
    {
      int signalIndex = -1;
      QVariantList signalData;
    };

    SignalWaiter(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    template <typename T, typename F, class Ret, class... Args>
    void addSignal(T* sender, Ret(F::*signal)(Args...))
    {
      auto connection = QObject::connect(sender, signal, this, [this, id = m_connections.length()](Args... args)
      {
        for_each_argument([this](const auto& arg) {
          m_result.signalData.append(QVariant::fromValue(arg));
        }, args...);

        m_result.signalIndex = id;
        m_handle.resume();
      });

      m_connections.append(connection);
    }

    bool await_ready() const;
    void await_suspend(coroutine_handle handle);
    Result await_resume();

  private:
    coroutine_handle m_handle;
    QList<QMetaObject::Connection> m_connections;
    Result m_result;
};
#endif // SIGNALWAITER_HPP
```

// signal_waiter.cpp

```
#include "signal_waiter.hpp"

SignalWaiter::SignalWaiter(QObject* parent) :
  QObject(parent)
{
}

bool SignalWaiter::await_ready() const
{
  return false;
}

void SignalWaiter::await_suspend(coroutine_handle handle)
{
  qDebug() << "SignalWaiter suspended";
  m_handle = handle;
}

SignalWaiter::Result SignalWaiter::await_resume()
{
  qDebug() << "SignalWaiter resumed";

  // disconnect
  for(const auto& connection : m_connections)
    QObject::disconnect(connection);

  auto result = m_result;

  //clear
  m_connections.clear();
  m_result = {};

  return result;
}
```

// coroutine.hpp

```
#ifndef COROUTINE_HPP
#define COROUTINE_HPP

#include <QtGlobal>
#if __has_include(<coroutine>)
#include <coroutine>
#else
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#endif

class Coroutine
{
  private:
#if __has_include(<coroutine>)
    using coroutine_handle = std::coroutine_handle<>;
    using suspend_never = std::suspend_never;
    using suspend_always = std::suspend_always;
#else
    using coroutine_handle = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<>;
    using suspend_never = std::experimental::suspend_never;
    using suspend_always = std::experimental::suspend_always;
#endif

    Coroutine() = default;

  public:
    struct promise_type
    {
      public:
        Coroutine get_return_object() { return {}; }
        suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
        suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    };
};

#endif // COROUTINE_HPP
```

// how to call the coroutine

```
  Coroutine function()
  {
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();

    MyClass myClass;

    SignalWaiter sw;
    sw.addSignal(&myClass, &MyClass::workFinished);

    qDebug() << "Start doing work.." << t.elapsed();
    myClass.doWork();
    auto result = co_await sw;
    qDebug() << "Work done!" << t.elapsed();
    qDebug() << "Result:" << result.signalIndex << result.signalData;
  }
```

Comment: Probably. Can you provide some more specifics on what you want to do with coroutines? For example, are you looking for a coroutine that will yield multiple values or one that will return a value, and will it need to await on any values? Is there a reason you particularly want to use coroutines for this over say threads? It might also help if you explained more about what you have in mind for the `doWork()` and `doSomethig()` functions.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz I have updated the code, can you please check it and provide some hints?